# Center buttons in a TStackPanel?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I found the `TStackPanel` control for C++ Builder and it sounded like what I needed.  I wanted to be able to put a ok/cancel button in it centered.  I set the panel horizontal and to center it but the buttons are still on the left side.   Did I do something wrong or does the panel not have that feature?

TIA!!

Comment: it's a completely different panel that had alignment options - just not implemented the way it could have been.   One issue with just plain panel is that I'm using alignment so on bottom it takes the full size and you can't center the two buttons in there (one can be, 3 can b3, but even numbers can't - one centered and other to right or left).

Answer (score 0):

Checked in Delphi:

Setting `HorizontalPosition = sphpCenter` works when `Orientation` is `spoVertical` and vice versa - `VerticalPosition` works when `Orientation` is `spoHorizontal`.

Not together.

Seems Delphi `TStackPanel` just implements behaviour of [Microsoft control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.stackpanel?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)  `StackPanel` that organizes children in hor/vert stack (according to its name)

> Arranges child elements into a single line that can be oriented
> horizontally or vertically

Comment: Oh bummer, so it looks like the stack is up/down or left/right and the orientation only applies to the opposite.  I had hoped it was smart enough to take the total controls with the spacing and center it even when resizing.  Back to the drawing board.  If there is something else that works automatically, it would be great to know what it is.

Comment: Sadly, don't know. If control set is static, it is possible to change Padding.Top (calculate it or visually)